# Is there a way to create an R function using a string formula with ', and " =~"?

Tags: r, function, stringr

I'm trying to create an R function that lets me specify latent variables and indicators. Is there a way to convert the following three code lines into a function?

```
            ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3 
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '
```

I tried using paste and paste0 but it didn't work very well. For example, using just one latent variable, I tried this:

```
myFunction <- function(z, x, ...) {
  latent_variable   <- paste0(x)
  latent_indicators <- paste0(..., collapse = " + ")
  latent_formula <- paste0(" ' ", latent_variable, "=", "~", latent_indicators, " ' ")
  
  fit <- cfa(latent_formula, data = z)
  
  summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
}

myFunction(HolzingerSwineford1939, "visual", c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error in lavParseModelString(model) : lavaan ERROR: left hand side (lhs) of this formula: 'visual =~ x1+x2+x3' contains either a reserved word (in R) or an illegal character: “'visual” See ?reserved for a list of reserved words in R Please use a variable name that is not a reserved word in R and use only characters, digits, or the dot symbol.
```

To give more context, this is where the function will be used. Please see code below:

```
library(lavaan)
library(lavaanPlot)

HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3 
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

fit <- cfa(HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939)

summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
        
lavaanPlot(model = fit)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you use R's formulas, as in `visual  ~ x1 + x2 + x3`? Using that, it can then be used with other R base functions (`model.matrix`?) directly instead of parsing strings.

Comment: @r2evans That's a good idea. I haven't tried model.matrix yet. Would it work with =~  ?

Comment: No, nothing in R natively works with `=~`, but many things work with `~`: it's its own thing, a `formula`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be pasting the single quotes into your formula. You are building the string already with `paste()`. Just use

```
latent_formula <- paste0(latent_variable, "=", "~", latent_indicators)
```

If you wanted to combine more than one responts, here's a function that will generate that formula

```
myFunction <- function(...) {
  params <- list(...)
  stopifnot(length(params)%%2==0)
  lefts = params[seq(1,length(params), by=2)]
  rights = params[seq(2,length(params), by=2)]
  rights <- Map(paste, rights, collapse="+")
  paste(paste0(lefts, " =~", rights), collapse="\n")
}

myFunction("visual", c("x1", "x2", "x3"), "textual", c("x4", "x5", "x6"), "speed", c("x7", "x8", "x9"))
```

Comment: It worked, but would I be able to do it for all three lines?

Comment: Well, how exactly do you want to call your function if you want it to run with all three lines? It's just a string so you can combine however many rows you like by pasting a "\n" (new line) between them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is very helpful. Eventually, I want to create a function that includes an infinite number of lines. Would I be able to specify that in the function? I'm also trying to figure out where to include the "\n".

Comment: The "\n" will separate the different lines. Without knowing what your input will look like, it's hard to say exactly what it should look like. But at the end of the day you are just building a string. There's nothing you shouldn't be able to do with `paste()`

Comment: I imagine it this way: `myFunction("visual", c("x1", "x2", "x3"), "textual", c("x4", "x5", "x6"), "speed", c("x7", "x8", "x9")) ` And eventually, I would like to do many lines, if possible.

Comment: I added a possible function to do that.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. But I'm unable to run it. Perhaps I am missing something. When I run your function I get this: `[1] "visual =~x1+x2+x3\ntextual =~x4+x5+x6\nspeed =~x7+x8+x9"` Also, how do I combine your function with my lavaan function?

Comment: That’s the value you pass as the first parameter to cfa(). It would perform the same as `HS.model`. So you can just save the result to that or some other variable.