# Creating an R function with a list of equations

Tags: r, function, parameters, arguments, stringr

I [asked a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748018/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-r-function-using-a-complicated-string-formula-using) and got help with creating a function with equations of the same type:

Converted this:

```
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3 
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '
```

to this:

```
myFunction <- function(...) {
  params <- list(...)
  lefts = params[seq(1,length(params), by=2)]
  rights = params[seq(2,length(params), by=2)]
  rights <- Map(paste, rights, collapse="+")
  paste(paste0(lefts, " =~", rights), collapse="\n")
```

which uses this input:

```
myFunction("visual", c("x1", "x2", "x3"), 
          "textual", c("x4", "x5", "x6"), 
          "speed"  , c("x7", "x8", "x9"))
```

This above function uses only "=~"
Now I would like to combine multiple types of equations such as "~~" and "~". For example, the list of equations would look like this:

```
model <- '
  # latent variable definitions (latvars)
    ind60 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
    dem60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
    dem65 =~ y5 + y6 + y7 + y8
  # regressions                 (regress)
    dem60 ~ ind60
    dem65 ~ ind60 + dem60
  # residual (co)variances      (covars)
    y1 ~~ y5
    y2 ~~ y4 + y6
    y3 ~~ y7
    y4 ~~ y8
    y6 ~~ y8
'
```

I imagine the new function input would look like:

```
myFunction(latvars = ("ind60", c("x1", "x2", "x3"), 
                      "dem60", c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"), 
                      "dem65", c("y5", "y6", "y7", "y8")),
           regress = ("dem60", c("ind60"),
                      "dem65", c("ind60", "dem60")),
           covars  = ("y1", c("y5"),
                      "y2", c("y4", "y6"),
                      "y3", c("y7"),
                      "y4", c("y8"),
                      "y6", c("y8"))
          )
```

I tried to do this

```
myFunction <- function(...) {
  params <- list(...)
  lefts = params[seq(1,length(params), by=2)]
  rights = params[seq(2,length(params), by=2)]
  rights <- Map(paste, rights, collapse="+")
  
  lefts2 = params[seq(3,length(params), by=2)]
  rights2 = params[seq(4,length(params), by=2)]
  rights2 <- Map(paste, rights2, collapse="+")

  paste(paste0(lefts, " =~", rights), paste0(lefts2, " ~", rights2), collapse="\n")

}
```

I'm obviously getting errors, and I'm unable to find a way to make the various arguments. Would like some help please. Thank you for your time.

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: note the error could be because of how you are passing arguments in `myFunction`. As i can see from your example `myFunction(latvars  = ('visual', c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'))`, you are passing argument incorrectly to a named argument `latvars`. Either you pass it as a vector or list.

Comment: Oh, I see. How do I pass it as a vector or a list?

Comment: vectors are formed with `c`, lists are formed with `list`?

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to generate the expression. Here I have tried to simplify the code and arguments. If you notice, the only difference between different model types is the separator you pass in, lhs and rhs remain similar.

So a common function which takes in the lhs and rhs and separator to separate both lhs and rhs. This function can be reused for other model types by changing the separator.

```r
input = list(
  'visual' = c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'),
  'textual' = c('x4', 'x5', 'x6'),
  'speed' = c('x7', 'x8', 'x9')
)

myFunc2 = function(variable, separator){
  #variable is a named list, where name is the lhs and values are the rhs
  lapply(
    list(names(variable)),
    paste,
    lapply(variable, paste, collapse = '+'),
    sep = separator
  )
}

myFunc2(input, '=')
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "visual=x1+x2+x3"  "textual=x4+x5+x6" "speed=x7+x8+x9"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Reusing the function over different model types:

```r
latvars = list('ind60' = c('x2', 'x3'), sep = '=')
regress = list('ind30' = c('x4', 'x5'), sep = '~~')

expr = list(latvars, regress)

output = c()

for(i in 1:2){
  output[i] = myFunc2(expr[[i]][1], expr[[i]][[2]])
}

output
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "ind60=x2+x3"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "ind30~~x4+x5"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>