# r Create measurement model lavaan using string formula

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function to easily run multiple lavaan mediation models with both the measurement part and the structural part, so I would only need to pass the names of the latent variables to the function call. I came across this nice solution for building the measurement part:

[Is there a way to create an R function using a string formula with ', and " =~"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748018/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-r-function-using-a-string-formula-with-and)

In my example, this looks like this (I later need the IV, mediator, and DV in the structural part):

```
model_lavaan <- function(IV, mediator, DV) {{
    measurement_part <- function(...) {
      params <- list(...)
      stopifnot(length(params)%%2==0)
      lefts = params[seq(1,length(params), by=2)]
      rights = params[seq(2,length(params), by=2)]
      rights <- Map(paste, rights, collapse="+")
      paste(paste0(lefts, " =~", rights), collapse="\n", "\n")
    }

      meas <- measurement_part(paste0(IV), c(paste0(IV,"_1"), paste0(IV, "_2"), paste0(IV,"_3")),
                               paste0(mediator), c(paste0(mediator,"_1"), paste0(mediator, "_2"), paste0(mediator,"_3")),
                               paste0(DV), c(paste0(DV,"_1"), paste0(DV, "_2"), paste0(DV,"_3")))
      meas
  }
}
```

My dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
         row.names = c("1","2","3","4","5",
                       "6","7","8","9","10","11"),
  T1finstrain_1 = c(5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5),
  T1finstrain_2 = c(4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2),
  T1finstrain_3 = c(5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4),
     T1concom_1 = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2),
     T1concom_2 = c(3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
     T1concom_3 = c(2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5),
    T2lifesat_1 = c(NA, 4, 5, 3, 3, NA, 5, NA, 2, NA, NA),
    T2lifesat_2 = c(NA, 3, 5, 2, 4, NA, 5, NA, 3, NA, NA),
    T2lifesat_3 = c(NA, 4, 5, 2, 5, NA, 5, NA, 3, NA, NA),
     T2jobsat_1 = c(NA, 5, 6, 6, 5, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA),
     T2jobsat_2 = c(NA, 5, 6, 6, 5, NA, 5, NA, 4, NA, NA),
     T2jobsat_3 = c(NA, 5, 6, 6, 5, NA, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA),
     T2jobsat_4 = c(NA, 5, 6, 6, 5, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA)
   )
```

So this works very well if all latent variables have three indicators:

```
model_lavaan(IV = "T1finstrain", mediator = "T1concom", DV = "T2lifesat")

#> [1] "T1finstrain =~T1finstrain_1+T1finstrain_2+T1finstrain_3 \n\nT1concom =~T1concom_1+T1concom_2+T1concom_3 \n\nT2lifesat =~T2lifesat_1+T2lifesat_2+T2lifesat_3 \n"
```

But it does not work out anymore if one variable has more indicators:

```
model_lavaan(IV = "T1finstrain", mediator = "T1concom", DV = "T2jobsat")

#> [1] "T1finstrain =~T1finstrain_1+T1finstrain_2+T1finstrain_3 \n\nT1concom =~T1concom_1+T1concom_2+T1concom_3 \n\nT2jobsat =~T2jobsat_1+T2jobsat_2+T2jobsat_3 \n"
```

I want to print the correct measurement part depending on the number of indicators in the dataframe. So if the suffixes range from 1:4, I want all four indicators in the measurement part. If they range from 1:6, I want to have all six etc.
In the case of the example dataframe `df`, for `DV = T2jobsat`, this should look like this :

```
model_lavaan(IV = "T1finstrain", mediator = "T1concom", DV = "T2jobsat")

#> "T1finstrain =~T1finstrain_1+T1finstrain_2+T1finstrain_3 \n\nT1concom =~T1concom_1+T1concom_2+T1concom_3 \n\nT2jobsat =~T2jobsat_1+T2jobsat_2+T2jobsat_3+T2jobsat_4 \n"
```

So the dataframe needs to be added as an argument to the function. But I do not really know how to accomplish what I want. I hope I explained this okay. Please ask if you need additional info! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be to pass the data frame to the function and access the variable names.

```
model_lavaan <- function(dat, IV, mediator, DV) {{
  measurement_part <- function(...) {
    params <- list(...)
    stopifnot(length(params)%%2==0)
    lefts = params[seq(1,length(params), by=2)]
    rights = params[seq(2,length(params), by=2)]
    rights <- Map(paste, rights, collapse="+")
    paste(paste0(lefts, " =~", rights), collapse="\n", "\n")
  }
  
  meas <- measurement_part(paste0(IV), grep(IV, names(dat), value = TRUE),
                           paste0(mediator), grep(mediator, names(dat), value = TRUE),
                           paste0(DV), grep(DV, names(dat), value = TRUE))
  meas
}
}
```

Then

```
cat(model_lavaan(df, IV = "T1finstrain", mediator = "T1concom", DV = "T2jobsat"))
```

gives

```
T1finstrain =~T1finstrain_1+T1finstrain_2+T1finstrain_3 

T1concom =~T1concom_1+T1concom_2+T1concom_3 

T2jobsat =~T2jobsat_1+T2jobsat_2+T2jobsat_3+T2jobsat_4
```

Comment: fantastic, that works well.